# Passing a row ID in a table to a modal in flask (python)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an HTML table which displays some data from a database table.Data is displayed by using a loop.Each row has a button that is also generated via a loop. Am using the button to edit data in a row. When a button is clicked, a modal pops up with data to be edited.The problem is that it only picks the first ID in the rows (i.e it picks only row one). Even when I click on row two button , the info displayed in the fields in the modal is for row one.Please any guide on how I will o about this ? How can I fix this ? Note : Am using flask

This is my code:

```html
<div>
   <table class="table" id="users">
         <thead>
            <tr class="success">
               <th>#</th>
               <th>Staff ID</th>
               <th>Role</th>
               <th>Designation</th>
               <th>Phone</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Department</th>
               <th>Edit</th>


            </tr>
         </thead>
         
         <tbody>
            {% for user in users %}
               <tr>
                  <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.staffid }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.role }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.designation }}</td>
                  <td>{{ user.phone }}</td>
                  <td> {{ user.email }} </td>
                  <td> {{ user.dept }} </td>
                  <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#edit' class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> EDIT </a></td>
                  
               </tr>
               <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit User Information </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form  method="post" action="/edit_profile">
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ user.staffid }}" name="staffid" required>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ user.role }}"  name="role" required>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ user.designation }}"  name="designation" required>
                                       </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
     
                     </div>
                  </div>
         </div>
  </div>
 <script> $('#edit').modal(show); </script>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#users').DataTable();
} );
  </script>          
             
<div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see you create a modal form for each user row. That's seems a bit costy to me as it means a lot of html when you have many rows. A better approach in my opinion would be to define only one modal and dynamically insert the content via Ajax.

However, the reason why your approach is not working is because you use the same id for each modal. Change the first line of your modal to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{ user.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and accordingly the line of your edit button:

```
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target='#edit{{ user.id }}' class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> EDIT </a></td>
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: I recently wrote a [post about using Ajax to handly modal Flask forms](http://mrl33h.de/post/21). This seems a better approach especially when it comes to saving the changed data.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Great ! I now realize where the problem was.  I have marked it as answer

Answer (score 1):

oh man, I was having the exactly same problem, also my modal was referring to the first element only. I've been trying to find the solution to this problem for 3 days straight and finally after hundreds of opened tabs, the post with only 1 answer from 5 years ago luckily showed up and my problem is solved. I specifcally created SO account just to thank you. I will stay here for longer. I shed a tear of happiness, can finally close those tabs and get some proper rest. THANK YOU!!!

I'm pasting my code just in case someone wanted to take something out of it, now that it works (I'm listing flashcard sets, each set comes with edit button to change its name, it's handled by two endpoints - one for listing said sets and one for changing its name)

sets.html:

```
{% for set in sets %}
  

<div class="setlist">
        <div style="display: flex">
            <div><a href="/flashcards/{{set.id}}">{{set.name}}</a></div>
            <div style="position:absolute; right:300px">Created on {{set.date_created.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}</div>
            <div style="position:absolute; right:250px">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-pen"></i>
                </a>
              
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                  <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit{{set.id}}" data-id="{{set.id}}">Change name</button>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/delete-set/{{set.id}}">Delete</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 1px; width:100%; margin-top: 10px; background-color:#B6A2A2"></div>
      </div>
    
    
        <!-- Update modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="edit{{set.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" style="font-family: Play;" id="updateModalLabel">Change set name</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="/change-set-name/{{set.id}}">
              <div class="modal-body">
                      <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;">
                          <input type="text" class="inmodalinput" name="updatesetname" id="updatesetname" placeholder="{{set.name}}">
                      </div>
              </div>
    
            <div style="text-align: center">
               <button type="submit" class="add_new_button">Save new name</button> 
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
@views.route("/sets", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def sets():
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
    fc_sets = user.sets

    if request.method == 'POST':
        set_name = request.form.get('setname')

        if not set_name:
            flash("Can't be empty", category="error")
        else:
            new_set = Set(name=set_name, user=current_user)
            db.session.add(new_set)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Set added!", category="success")
            return redirect(url_for("views.sets"))

    return render_template("sets.html", fc_sets=fc_sets)


@views.route("/change-set-name/<id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def change_set_name(id):
    fc_set = Set.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    

    if not fc_set:
        flash("No set found", category='error')
    else:
        fc_set.name = request.form.get('updatesetname')
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Set name updated", category='success')
    
    
    return redirect(url_for("views.sets"))
```